# Lowercase based on regex pattern in Django & Python

Tags: python, django, regex

The script I am using calls  `s_lower` method to transform all text to lowercase but there is a catch: if it is a link (there is a special regex), then it does not lowercase it. So, I would like to apply the same or similar logic with other regex.

```py
RE_WEBURL_NC = (
    r"(?:(?:(?:(?:https?):)\/\/)(?:(?!(?:10|127)(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!(?:169\.254|192\.168)(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!172\.(?:1["
    r"6-9]|2\d|3[0-1])(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])(?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\.(?"
    r":[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z0-9][a-z0-9_-]{0,62})?[a-z0-9]\.)+(?:[a-z]{2,}\.?))(?::\d{2,5})?)(?:"
    r"(?:[/?#](?:(?![\s\"<>{}|\\^~\[\]`])(?!&lt;|&gt;|&quot;|&#x27;).)*))?"
)

def s_lower(value):
    url_nc = re.compile(f"({RE_WEBURL_NC})")

    # Do not lowercase links
    if url_nc.search(value):
        substrings = url_nc.split(value)
        for idx, substr in enumerate(substrings):
            if not url_nc.match(substr):
                substrings[idx] = i18n_lower(substr)
        return "".join(substrings)

    return i18n_lower(value)
```

I want to lowercase all text other than text inside the special tags.

```py
def s_lower(value):
    spec_nc = re.compile(r"\[spec .*\]") # this is for [spec some raNdoM cAsE text here]

    if spec_nc.search(value):
        substrings = spec_nc.split(value)
        for idx, substr in enumerate(substrings):
            if not spec_nc.match(substr):
                substrings[idx] = i18n_lower(substr)
        return "".join(substrings)

    return i18n_lower(value)
```

Comment: For your other question, if you don't have multiple levels of nested `[]` you could use `\[spec\s+(\[[^]]*\]|[^]]|\n)*\]\s?\n?` https://regex101.com/r/6OK8Gb/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was writing this as a comment, but it got too long...

You haven't actually said what your problem is, but it looks like you're missing the `()` around the regex (so that the split string ends up in `substrings`). It should be

```
spec_nc = re.compile(r"(\[spec .*\])")
```

Note:

- you should use `[^]]*` instead of `.*` to ensure your match stays within a single set of `[]`.
- you don't really need to `search`, if the string is not present then `split` will simply return the original string in a single element list which you can still iterate
- you don't need the call to `match`; the strings which match the split regex will *always* be in the odd indexes of the list so you can just lower case dependent on `idx`

So you can simplify your code to:

```
def s_lower(value):
    spec_nc = re.compile(r"(\[spec [^]]*\])") # this is for [spec some raNdoM cAsE text here]
    
    substrings = spec_nc.split(value)
    for idx, substr in enumerate(substrings):
        if idx % 2 == 0:
            substrings[idx] = i18n_lower(substr)
    return "".join(substrings)
```

Comment: @TToprak1 can you give some sample data which shows a problem? Here's a demo of it working fine for me: https://ideone.com/WLkB91

Comment: I just double checked, it works but here are my questions: 1) What is the difference between putting `?` after `.*` like `.*?` and `[^]`. 2) How about if I still want to keep the links as they are + this special tag.

Comment: #1: Putting `?` after `.*` will have the same effect as `[^]]*` but `[^]]*` is more efficient. #2: I'm not sure exactly what you mean?

Comment: See the step counts in https://regex101.com/r/1kNezi/1 and https://regex101.com/r/Zljff7/1

Comment: So, do not lowercase links (script's default logic that I want to keep) + do not lowercase the text that inside [spec] tag. So Assuming this solution only works for  [spec] tag.

Comment: It will work, you can just use `spec_nc = re.compile(r"((?:\[spec [^]]*\])|(?:RE_WEBURL_NC))")`

Comment: Now it doesn't work. Can you please double check `spec_nc = re.compile(r"((?:\[spec [^]]*\])|(?:RE_WEBURL_NC))")`, is it correct?

Comment: @TToprak1 that should work... can you give me some sample data?

Comment: [spec CAPITAL] returns as lowercase capital

Comment: @TToprak1 it works for me: https://ideone.com/fMWnSy

Comment: I think something else going on in the script, it's more complicated then I thought but thank you so much for the help, I'll try to figure it out.

Comment: You could always ask another question with all the code in it... Good luck!

Comment: I updated my question with a more complex tag. Should I ask a new question or can you edit your answer based on my updates?

Comment: @TToprak1 that sounds like you've got a different issue, so you really should ask another question. Please do include some sample data which demonstrates the problem